# Changing an input value with jQuery updates attribute but not input

Tags: jquery, input

I'm using jquery to update the value of an input. I `console.log` the value and it's correct. Upon inspection the `value` attribute is updated but the input is still blank. When I save the value doesn't get passed.

The code uses wordpress to get the value but all it's doing is passing the value to jQuery so it can insert the value.

```
$('.get-video').click(function(e) {

    // Clear out current targets
    $('.video').removeClass('currentValue');

    // Add class to elements in current target area
    $(this).closest('td').find('.video').addClass('currentValue');

    e.preventDefault();
    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
        console.log(attachment.url);
        $('.currentValue').attr('value',attachment.url);
    };
    wp.media.editor.open($(this));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Dear Friend please post the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Added code. This is in wordpress but the `wp.media.editor.send.attachment` just grabs the file location value and passes to JS.

Comment: Try $('.currentValue').val(attachment.url);

Comment: @SudharsanS I did and it doesn't set the `value` attribute at OR the input.

Comment: what html element is .currentValue?

Comment: if your element is an  <input type='file />  tag, you can't modify its value through javascript AFAIK.

Comment: @madalinivascu The target input type is `type="text"`